# Powershell | Rename file with random name

Tags: powershell

I'm making a script to rename a specific file with a random name. But when running, the following error always occurs:

```html
It is not possible to convert the value ".jpg" to the type "System.Int32". Error: "The input string was not in the correct format."
In C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\SetDiscordWallpaper\SetDiscordWallpaper.ps1:7 character:7
+       Rename-Item -Path $file.FullName -NewName ($random + $file.Exte ...
+       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidCastFromStringToInteger
```

Here is the code I am using

```html
function Set-DiscordWallpaper {
  $path = "C:\Windows\Temp\*" 

  foreach($file in $(Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Include "Wallpaper.jpg")) {
      $extension = [System.IO.Path]::GetExtension($file.FullName);
      $randomName = [System.IO.Path]::ChangeExtension([System.IO.Path]::GetRandomFileName(), $extension)
      $newPath = "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\"
  
      Write-Host "Changing File $($file.Name) to $randomName"
  
      Move-Item -Path $file.FullName -Destination $newPath
   }
  }
```

I ask you to help me please. I'm waiting the answer. Thanks

Comment: The error message is from Rename-Item, but that command is not in your sample code?

Answer (score 0):

The code (second part in your question) creates the new random filename just fine, only the line `Move-Item -Path $file.FullName -Destination $newPath` does nothing with that new name and moves the file with its **original** name to the new path.

Change that line to

```
Move-Item -Path $file.FullName -Destination (Join-Path -Path $newPath -ChildPath $randomName)
```

so the file gets moved with the random name in the new path.

---

Or is your intention to copy the file to its new destination keeping the **original** filename there and after that rename the original?

In that case do:

```
  Write-Host "Changing File $($file.Name) to $randomName"
  Copy-Item -Path $file.FullName -Destination $newPath  # copy with original name
  $file | Rename-Item -NewName $randomName              # rename the original file
```